# Making DATE bold when its about to reach current date & etc

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a DATE stored in php mysql.

Table name is : `Companies` & column name is `Validity`

The `Validity` is basically like product expiry date.

How can it be made bold when current date difference is 30 days or so & if current date crossed the `Validity`  then it should be made italic.

Example:

`XYZ Company validity is : 2016-04-28`

`Current date: 2016-03-30`

Here difference is less than 30 days so Validity date must be bold here.

& If current date is 2016-04-29 then `Validity` date must be italic.

Comment: By using `<b>` or `<strong>` HTML tags? Show us your code and what you have tried.

Comment: I m display date in normal format just like php echo $row[date]

Which returns like 2016-04-28 @Mike

Comment: You need to turn error reporting on because that code should produce a warning. Try `echo '<b>'.$row['date'].'</b>';`

Comment: I guess u didn't get my question.

How do we show bold if validitydate is near current ie 30days.

Something like in godaddy when product expires.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($Validity);
$datetime2 = new DateTime('now');
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
$diff=$interval->format('%R%a');

if($diff<0){echo "<i>";}
if($diff<=30 &&$diff >=0){echo "<b>";}
    echo $Validity;
if($diff<0){echo "</i>";}
            if($diff<=30 &&$diff >=0){echo "</b>";}
```